# Probabiity of a graph containg hamiltonian cycle with given probabily for and edge between any two vertices.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Consider a non-oriented graph with **n vertices:** {1 ... n}.

Let $ p \in [0,1]$ is the probability of having an edge between any two vertices.
The probability of having an edge is the same for any two vertices.

So I have two tasks:

- a) Find the probability of having a hamiltonian cycle in the graph.
- b) What is the probability of havin a hamiltonian cycle if we know that $(1)-(2) \dots - (k)$
  is a path in the graph.

My attempt for a):

So  we have (n - 1)! different options for a hamiltonian cycle.

The probability of having (for example) this ham cycle: $(1)-(2) \dots (n) - (1)$ is $p^{n}$

So the probability that the graph DOES NOT contain a ham cycle is $1 - (p^n)^{(n-1)!} $

But the problem is that I consider that the existence of the different ham paths are indpendent, which is obviously not true.

Any tips?

Comment: This problem is too complicated to give a formula in terms of $n$. This question might be answerable if you edit it so you are only asking for an upper/lower bound, or an approximation in some sense. Please edit, and be precise as to what your needs are.

Comment: I am precise. This is my assigned task. I guess a upper/lower bound would be a satisfying answer.

Comment: Really, someone just assigned you to "find the probability", with no restrictions on $n$? There is no way that is a fair assignment; I am certain the problem as you phrased it is intractable (anyone else reading these comments, please weigh in). Are you sure you are not leaving out some context?

Comment: This is definitely not a reasonable question to ask as stated. We could ask about the *expected number* of Hamiltonian cycles, and then we would be more in the realm of random graph theory. We can also find the threshold probability $p$ at which Hamiltonian cycles become likely, but that's not an easy task.

Comment: Perhaps this is a misunderstanding along the likes of the tale in which Georg Dantzig found a homework assignment to be "a little harder than usual," in 1939?